# Grouped bar chart from two pandas data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames containing different values but the same structure:

df1 =

```
         0         1         2         3         4 
D  0.003073  0.014888  0.155815  0.826224       NaN
E  0.000568  0.000435  0.000967  0.002956  0.067249
```

df2 =

```
     0         1         2         3         4
D  0.746689  0.185769  0.060107  0.007435       NaN   
E  0.764552  0.000000  0.070288  0.101148  0.053499
```

I want to plot both data frames in a single grouped bar chart. In addition, each row (index) should be a subplot.

This can be easily achieved for one of them using pandas directly:

```
df1.T.plot(kind="bar", subplots=True, layout=(2,1), width=0.7, figsize=(10,10), sharey=True)
```

I tried to join them using

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

which results in a new dataframe:

```
         0         1         2         3         4         0         1         2         3         4
D  0.003073  0.014888  0.155815  0.826224       NaN  0.746689  0.185769  0.060107  0.007435       NaN
E  0.000568  0.000435  0.000967  0.002956  0.067249  0.764552  0.000000  0.070288  0.101148  0.053499
```

However, plotting the data frame with the above method will not group the bars per column but rather treats them separately. Per subplot this results in a x-axis with duplicated ticks in order of the columns, e.g. `0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not exactly clear how the data is organized. Pandas and seaborn usually expect [tidy datasets](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/Tidy_Data_In_Python?lang=en). Because you do transpose the data prior to plotting I assume you have two variable (A and B) and four observations (e.g. measurements)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(np.random.rand(2,4), index = ['A','B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(np.random.rand(2,4), index = ['A','B'])

df1.T
```

[image]

Maybe this is close to what you want:

```
df4 = pd.concat([df1.T, df2.T], axis=0, ignore_index=False)
df4['col'] = (len(df1.T)*(0,) + len(df2.T)*(1,))
df4.reset_index(inplace=True)
df4
```

[image]

using seaborns facet grid allows for convenient plotting:

```
sns.factorplot(x='index', y='A', hue='col', kind='bar', data=df4)
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly how I did it. Thanks!